# Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270 not showing the preview correctly, why?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, webcam

Hi I can't see the preview correctly on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (running under VM). Looks like the decoder is failing but I am not sure.

Here is my setup

```
gustavo@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
gustavo@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual USB Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Here is what I get with guvcview

[image]

I see a bunch of

```
V4L2_CORE: (jpeg decoder) error while decoding frame
V4L2_CORE: (jpeg decoder) error while decoding frame
V4L2_CORE: (jpeg decoder) error while decoding frame
V4L2_CORE: (jpeg decoder) error while decoding frame
V4L2_CORE: (jpeg decoder) error while decoding frame
V4L2_CORE: (jpeg decoder) error while decoding frame
```

I also tried cheese and it was even worse. Completely back as below:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix these issues? I think it is the decoder but I am not the savvy with Linux to fix it.

thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. remember to also enable all the usb internal hubs to which the webcam is connected
2. if it's a USB3 hub, remember to enable USB3 support (no USB1/2 support will not work)

after that, my machine worked on Virtualbox with a Logitech C920